# Hide my bound google scripts for all users besides my account

Tags: google-apps-script

I have Google sheet and script bound to him
How i can hide my bound google scripts for all users besides my account.
for example im share for edit my sheet, and dont't want what all users can view my google script code

Comment: Turn your script into an [add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the answer in the comment, there is no way of doing that.